# How to migrate wordpress to new server without database files?

Tags: database, wordpress

I only have the main wordpress files from my old site and the xml file for the posts and pages. Is this all I need to put the site on a new server? Or do I need to import the database from the other server?

Comment: The XML file acts as a substitute for the MySQL database. You can upload the XML file and restore your blog's content via the administrator dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Having the database is ideal as it will have all your plugin and
   administration settings in it.
2. The XML export file has the post and page content (but not images and
   files attached to them).
3. You'll also want to make sure you have all the content in the
   uploads folder, images and files that were uploaded into the 
   Wordpress admin.